# Creating DataFrame with both aggregated and unaggregated columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to create a data frame that combines series that I have aggregated using .groupby method with series from the original data frame. When I run the code below, it returns the error **"object of type 'int' has no len()"** I can run this data frame with either just the grouped series or the original series but I cannot with both. Can someone explain this to me?

`total_value = df.groupby(["Item ID", "Item Name"])["Price"].sum()`

`purchase_count = (df.groupby(["Item ID", "Item Name"])["Price"].count().sort_values(ascending=False))`

`most_pop = pd.DataFrame({ "Item ID": df["Item ID"], "Item Name": df["Item Name"], "Purchase Count": purchase_count, "Item Price": df["Price"], "Total Purchase Value": total_value})`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
most_pop = df.groupby(["Item ID", "Item Name"], as_index=False).agg({"Price": ["sum", "count"]})

# just to adjust multilevel columns to your naming convention:
most_pop.columns = map("_".join, most_pop)
most_pop = most_pop.rename(columns={"Price_sum": "Total Purchase Value", "Price_count": "Purchase Count"})
```